# Book reference for Analytical 3D geometry

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry, 3d, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book which covers the following topics:

Generating lines, Cone, Cylinder, Paraboloid, Ellipsoid, Hyperboloid of one and two sheets. Their tangent planes, normal lines, director sphere and curves formed by intersection of these surfaces.

Though Joseph Wolstenholme - A Treatise on Solid Geometry contains most of the topics but it lacks details and very few worked out problem.

Comment: Have you tried Kiselev's Geometry / Book II. Stereometry?

Comment: No let me check.

Comment: It may not be that analytic though...Try Analytical Geometry of Three Dimensions by William McCrea

Comment: @YuiToCheng no man again only theoretical.

Comment: Try 'An Elementary treatise on 3D Analytical Geometry' - Robert T.J. Bell.

Comment: Thanks @Quasar. I think that will do the job.